# until loop is not working with string comparison in shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

In the following bash shell script until loop is not working properly.

```
cm_health_check=$(curl -X GET -u "admin:admin" http://$HOSTNAME:7180/api/v11/cm/service/ | jq '
.entityStatus')
echo $cm_health_check
until [ $cm_health_check -eq "GOOD_HEALTH" ]
do
   cm_health_check=$(curl -X GET -u "admin:admin" http://$HOSTNAME:7180/api/v11/cm/service/ | jq '
.entityStatus')
done
```

output

```
 + curl -X GET -u admin:admin http://abcd.xyz.com:7180/api/v11/cm/service/
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 
    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
    0   503    0     0  17023      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 17344
 "STARTING"
 + echo '"STARTING"'
 + [ '"STARTING"' -eq GOOD_HEALTH ]
```

until loop is not waiting for status to get **GOOD_HEALTH** , what am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-eq` operator is for *numerics,* not strings. For strings, you'd want `=`. If you look into the `bash` documentation, you'll see (my emphasis):

> `arg1 OP arg2`:
> `OP` is one of `-eq`, `-ne`, `-lt`, `-le`, `-gt`, or `-ge`.
> These ***arithmetic*** binary operators return true if `arg1` is equal to, not equal to, less than, less than or equal to, greater than, or greater than or equal to `arg2`, respectively.
> `Arg1` and `arg2` may be ***positive or negative integers.***

For example:

```
pax:~> [[ 'xx' = 'yy' ]] && echo WTF
pax:~> [[ 'xx' -eq 'yy' ]] && echo WTF
WTF
```

Comment: I was about to type that.  The notation is the opposite of the way Perl does it — there, the alphanumeric operator names such as `eq` are for comparing strings and the arithmetic operators such as `==` are for comparing numbers.

Comment: @paxdiablo : Since we are in bash here, we should emphasize that `==` does not do simple equality comparision, but pattern matching, where the rhs is interpreted as wildcard pattern, unless quoted. Example: With `f='r*'`, `[[ rx == $f ]]` matches, but `[[ rx == "$f" ]]` does not.

Comment: @user1934428, I'm not sure that comes into play here since `'GOOD_HEALTH'` has no wildcards - from memory, wild-card matching only works if the wildcarded thing is on the right of the `=`. In other words, `[ $f = rx ]` also does not. But I'll make an addendum to call this out.

Comment: In this case, no. I thought it's good to mention it for correctness. Of course if you use the _test_  command (`[ xx = yy ]`), you always have pure string equality.

Comment: Hi @paxdiablo now until loop is going in infinite loop. `+ cm_health_check='"GOOD_HEALTH"' `
`+ [ '"GOOD_HEALTH"' '=' GOOD_HEALTH ] `